# AS3 Button States

Tags: actionscript-3, button, mouseevent, event-listener

I have 7 buttons on my stage (buttonA, buttonB, etc) all MC's.
I would like to control the RollOver, RollOut & CLick with AS3.

At first I thought I could just tell my button Listener where to go

i.e. gotoAndStop(2) which is RollOver state.
or gotoAndStop(3) which is Click state.
and gotoAndStop(1) which is RollOut state.

But when I "Click" and then rollout, I need the button to stay "clicked" until some other button is "clicked".

can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it would be quicker and more efficient if you name your buttons numerically.  button1, button2, button2.. this will allow you to write for loops to perform functions easily

```
// loop through the buttons and give them mouse click listeners
for ( var i:int = 1 ; i <= 7; i++ ){
    var curButton:MovieClip = getChildByName ("button"+i);
    // set click lisitener
    curButton.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler );
    // set rollover listener
    curButton.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.ROLLOVER, buttonRollOverHandler );
    // set rollout listener
    curButton.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.ROLLOUT, buttonRollOutHandler );

    // set initial state
    curButton.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function resetStates (){
    for ( var i = 1; i<=7; i++){
       var curButton = getChildByName("button"+i);
       curButton.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}

function buttonRollOverHandler ( evt:MouseEvent ){
    resetStates();
    evt.target.gotoAndStop(2);
}
function buttonRollOutHandler ( evt:MouseEvent ){
    resetStates();
}
function buttonClickHandler ( evt:MouseEvent ){
    resetStates ();
    evt.target.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Comment: +1, although I would probably initially place the buttons in an array, rather than relying on using getChildByName.

Comment: @Allan @guacamoly  I figured the 1st part out with your help, THANK! Now I need to run the entire animation until the user interacts with it. So in other words I need to simulate the buttons being pressed in order (first to last) until a user actually interacts with the slideshow.

Comment: you can do that by using the setInterval method.  setInterval allows you to call a function after a specific time interval. look it up in the documentation.  Every time the function gets called toggle the state of the next button and reset the others. 
To have the animation stop when the user mouses over any button.. use clearInterval in the buttonRollOverHandler.   And to have it restart setInterval to that same animation function inside  buttonRollOutHandler

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

I would keep the roll over and press functionality within the scope of a button element and do a frame two for the permanent clicked state.

[this is quickly written code, but you'll get the idea]

It seems you'll need have some parent "reset" function and individual click handlers for each button.

```
buttonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, buttonADown);


function resetButtons(){
    buttonA.gotoAndStop(1);
    buttonB.gotoAndStop(1);
    buttonC.gotoAndStop(1);
    buttonD.gotoAndStop(1);
    buttonE.gotoAndStop(1);
    buttonF.gotoAndStop(1);
    buttonG.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function buttonADown(e.Mouse_Event):void{

    resetButtons(); //RESET ALL PREVIOUSLY CLICKED BUTTONS
    buttonA.gotoAndStop(2);
}

// and so  on down the line....
```